Studying obfuscation
I am solving a crackme and I'm a complete new to this. There is very little information on the Internet on how to solve such problems.That's why I decided to study obfuscation to understand how it works, if I can understand how it works then I will be able to find signatures in the code.
Where can I read more about obfuscation? What are the good resources to understand the techniques and required programming?
I'm solving this crackme.

If you're searching for information about obfuscation in a context of CTFs and/or crackmes, you can read the writeups for CTF tasks: https://ctftime.org/writeups or search for obfuscation/deobfuscation on this site with google: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fctftime.org+deobfuscation.
Some of these writeups are labeled with tags, but the vast majority are not.
https://ctftime.org/writeups?tags=deobfuscation&hidden-tags=deobfuscation
https://ctftime.org/writeups?tags=obfuscation&hidden-tags=obfuscation
